Behavior of Badlands winch when Stopping Under Load
My experience with several Badlands winches is that when they run in one direction lifting, they exhibit reduced speed if the load is heavy. But upon reversal, the motor runs faster though not so fast that the speed is out of control - the load is nowhere near freefall but definitely faster than the lifting portion of the operation.
I have about six of these winches - I use two per lift mechanism. One moves the load horizontally and the other moves the load vertically. Both of these motors runs until a limit switch tells it to stop and the mechanism runs into a solid impediment. When the stops that the load encounters are the right ones, the microprocessor's code causes the first motor to stop and the second motor kicks in to lower the load. The load drops at a rate commensurate with the weight of the load and definitely proportionate to the speed of the motor in reverse.
These winches have 'auto dynamic braking'
On another version of the lift mechanism only vertical motion is used. As I have built this second version, I have noticed that the lift has been stopping as described, but suddenly as I was probing around it trying to get other things to work, it stopped working so that now it unwinds a small bit - just enough to reverse off the stop and switch that should have held the motor still.
What is causing the motor to turn backward like that now after not working like this for a very long time? What could be wrong with the motor to cause it? I verified that the cable is not slipping and I even replaced the motor/winch with a different motor/winch After replacement the motor stopped correctly for awhile but then began to fail by running back for a bit before stopping. It is not running back, but turning backward as though being overloaded.
I am using proximity switches to determine the mechanism state and the state of the remote is provided by the voltage level on the motor controller. The Raspberry Pi Pico is used to determine what happens next from these inputs. I need to know what does the auto dynamic braking and how do I fix this?

May be worth accepting an answer on your other question.

You are correct in determining that the motor behaves as if overloaded. When you cut off power, it becomes overloaded. The gearbox, brake, etc take a bit of movement in the other direction to kick in the stop. The amount of movement required likely increases a bit from the device being broken in.

Sorry, am I missing something? I only have one question and no answers. The motor is acting as though it is overloaded when clearly it is not. And it just started  doing this with the same relative load as it had before.  My question is how this braking is accomplished and how can I fix it? I just want it to return to its original capabilities.
